# Can't save current user as object in User Pointer column (Parse4J)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, parse-platform, parse-server, parse4j

I'm trying to save the currentUser to the Pointer<_User> column in one of my classes. This is a library-specific problem (https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/parse4j/ParseUser.java). I'm just wondering if anybody else has had a similar issue.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.currentUser;

ParseObject sentRequest = new ParseObject(ParseConstantsUtil.CLASS_REQUEST);
sentRequest.put("author", currentUser);
try {
 sentRequest.save();
} catch (org.parse4j.ParseException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**pom.xml:** I'm using the latest SNAPSHOT build as my Parse4J dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.thiagolocatelli</groupId>
        <artifactId>parse4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Exception:**

```
ParseException [code=111, error=schema mismatch for Request.author; expected Pointer<_User> but got Pointer<users>]
    at org.parse4j.command.ParseResponse.getParseError(ParseResponse.java:122)
    at org.parse4j.command.ParseResponse.getException(ParseResponse.java:78)
    at org.parse4j.ParseObject.save(ParseObject.java:486)
    at com.test.automation.controller.RequestController.createRequestObject(RequestController.java:119)
    at com.test.automation.controller.RequestController.saveRequest(RequestController.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when you query for the current user, but I think that's definitely an unnecessary additional call. I'd love to know why my first attempt fails...

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> userQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
        userQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", currentUser.getObjectId());
        try {
            List<ParseObject> userList = userQuery.find();
            for (ParseObject author : userList) {

                sentRequest.put("author", author);
                try {
                    sentRequest.save();
                } catch (org.parse4j.ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } catch (org.parse4j.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```